# validate html controls dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate a html page where controls are added dynamically.

My code look like following

```
function validateComments() {            
        var errorcheck = 0;           

        $("[id^=txt_comments]").each(function () {
            var comment = $.trim($(this).val());
            $("[id^=validate]").each(function () {

                var value = $(this).val();
                if (comment == 0 && value == "Yes") {                      
                    errorcheck = 1;
                }
            });               

        });
        if (errorcheck == 1) {
                // Show error message
            }
        else {
            ErrorHide();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

So my page has a `<textarea>` HTML control(with id 'txt_comments') and a `<select>` HTML control(with id 'validate').

This  control has options:  'Select a Value', 'Yes', 'No'

So each textarea has a respective select(dropdown).

And these controls are added dynamically.

My validation rule is:

- User has to select any value from dropdown
- If user selects 'Yes', respective textarea should have some text(minimum 1 character, maximum 1000 characters)
- If user selects 'No', textarea can be blank or disabled.

I am able to validate either a textarea or dropdown. I am unable to validate both at the same time.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED:

My HTML dynamic code generation from VB.NET

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder

sb.Append("<table border='0'cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='50%' class ='tabledata' id='tblContent'>")
For Each item As myObject In myLst            
    sb.Append("<tr><td style='width:50%;' valign='top'>")
    sb.Append("<textarea id=txt_comments" & i & " name='txt_comments' rows='5' cols='60'></textarea></td>")
    sb.Append("<td style='width:15%' valign='top' align='center'><select ID = validate" & i & " name=ValidateValues style ='border:1;width:150px'><option value = ''>Select</option><option value = 'Yes'>Yes</option><option value = 'No'>No</option><br /><br /></td>")
                sb.Append("</tr><tr>")
Next
sb.Append("</table>")
myContent.InnerHtml = sb.ToString
```

Comment: Show your html would be great assistance to us to help you

Comment: how do you know wich textArea goes with wich dropdown?

Comment: Also you should never have more than 1 element with the same Id

Comment: @CalvinNunes added my HTML code as well

Comment: @LioraHaydont I am looping through each, so I have in each loop corresponding textarea and dropdown

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many different ways to go about what you are doing; but I'll answer in the simplest form. Basically; watch the change value of the `<select />` control; then, validate it's corresponding `<textarea />` based on the indexed position.

```
function validate() {
    var haserror = false;
    $("select[id^=validate]").each(function(i){
        var targ = 'txt_comments'+i;
        if (this.value=='Yes') {              
            if (0 == $.trim(document.getElementById(targ).value).length) {
                console.log(targ + ' is required');
                haserror = true;
            }
        }
    });

    return haserror;
}
```

Comment: This is not working as expected. Actually I have more than 1 set of controls(a textbox and dropdown). It is validating only for the first time. User can enter text first and select value from dropdown next or vice versa and click on the button. We need to validate on the button client click

Comment: all you would need to do is remove the `.change` event'  and wrap a function around the rest; I'll update my code to illustrate.